# Merge two JSON outputs into one with Dataweave

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I currently have two JSON files with data.

The first has a list of actions by a user.  However, the userID is a UID string instead of their user name.

The second is a JSON list of UID strings with their corresponding user names. I stored this JSON in a Flow Variable named UserPayload

I'd like to merge the user name into the first list so that my output has actual users names instead of the UID.

Here is what I had so far...but the userId part doesn't work since my flowVar is an list.
[image: UserPayload FlowVar]

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/csv
---
payload map ((payload01, indexOfPayload01) -> {
     user: payload.01.userId,
     actions: payload01.action,
     FileName: payload01.payload.properties.name default "N/A",
     userId: flowVars.UserPayload.objectName
})
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: sample data provided by **you** would motivate more people to help you.

Comment: good point...noted.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can access the right object from the `UserPayload` flowVar by either filtering the content of `UserPayload` based on `userId` or creating a associative array from `UserPayload`.

**filtering UserPayload**

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload map (action, index) -> {
    user: action.user,
    action: action.action,
    FileName: action.FileName,
    userId: (flowVars.UserPayload filter $.objectId == action.user)[0].objectName
}
```

**associative array**

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%var users = flowVars.UserPayload groupBy $.objectId
---
payload map (action, index) -> {
    user: action.user,
    action: action.action,
    FileName: action.FileName,
    userId: users[action.user][0].objectName
}
```

for my examples i used following sample data derived from your question.

**flowVars.UserPayload**

```
[{
    "objectId": "0000-0000-0001",
    "objectName": "first user"
}, {
    "objectId": "0000-0000-0002",
    "objectName": "second user"
}]
```

**payload**

```
[{
    "user": "0000-0000-0001",
    "action": "some crazy action",
    "FileName": "some-crazy-action.mov"
}]
```

Comment: The associative array worked for me.  The other one did not.  Thank you for the help!